# Something strange in the BIN2DEC function

Tags: google-sheets

I was playing with the BIN2DEC function and for some reason when I calculate 10 digits, and the left most digit is 1, the number turns negative.
For example =BIN2DEC(1010111110) gives the answer -322 while it should give the answer 702
However, if I use 9 digits (or less) in my binary number, this doesn't happen. for example:
=BIN2DEC(101011110) equals 350 as it should
I'm curious as to why that is. Thanks

Comment: Documentation: The most significant bit of signed_binary_number is the sign bit; that is, negative numbers are represented in two's complement format.

For this function, the input value has a maximum of 0111111111 if positive, and a minimum of 1000000000 if negative.

Comment: If you need to be able to process 10 bit unsigned numbers, you can always add 1024 (which is 2^10) to the output of bin2dec when the input is 10 bit.

Answer (score 1):

As the other user commented, the BIN2DEC function assumes the argument provided is a signed binary number.

Here's what you can try instead:

```
=LET(n,1010111110,l,LEN(n),s,SEQUENCE(l),SUMPRODUCT(MID(n,s,1),2^(l-s)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually not looking for a fix for this, my question is in order to understand what happened. Do you mean that 10 digits indicate that the left most character (1/0( decides if the value is negative or positive, but for any other number of digits it is just treated as a number?

Comment: it's not that the leftmost bit "decides" the sign. When using 2's complement the leftmost digit of a negative number is always a 1 but it's not because we put the 1 there, it's because of how the number is constructed. You can watch this [short video](https://youtu.be/Z3mswCN2FJs?feature=shared) to better understand what is it and why it's used.

Comment: Thanks, I've watched the video and I understand a bit more. Still not sure why it only happens with 10 digits and never with 9 or less digits